# Перенаправленние на другой раздел сайта

Tags: javascript

Когда открываю ссылку в браузере, нужно чтобы  браузер перенаправлял на другой раздел сайта, просто скопировать ссылку не получается, так как она прикручена через js. Подскажите что нужно прописать в js чтобы сразу открывалась нужная мне ссылка.

Comment: в js надо написать `<script>location.href="новая ссылка";</script>` но это какашка какая-то,а не решение

Comment: К сожалению этот вариант не работает, страница начинает тупо рефрешить каждую секунду.

Comment: если вы этот код пропишете на каждой странице, то, конечно, так и будет

Comment: а зачем так? пропишите сразу нормальные редиректы или это нужно чтобы переводить со страниц потерявших актуальность? Если нужно решать проблему с устареванием не лучше ли пользователю прокинуть баннер с сообщением "страница устарела, клик вот сюда!"?